# LAMP server on EC2 (Amazon Linux Micro Instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

I've launched an instance of the Basic 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI which has an 8GB volume as it's root device. If I terminate it, the EBS volume is destroyed as well. What I'd like to know is whether or not my data is protected (for example, the apache document root, or MySQL data) if the server crashes? A lot of tutorials seem to indicate that another EBS volume should be created and my data stored on that, but I'm not really seeing why two EBS volumes are needed?

Or is the current setup okay for a web server setup?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you spin an EC2 instance up, the root volume is ephemeral - that is, when the instance is terminated, the root volume is destroyed** (taking any data you put there with it). It doesn't matter how you partition that ephemeral volume and where you tuck your data on it - when it is destroyed, everything contained in that volume is lost.

So if the data in the volume is entirely transient and fully recoverable/retrievable from somewhere else the next time you need it, there's no problem; terminate the instance, then spin a new one up and re-acquire the data you need to carry on working.

However, if the data is NOT transient, and needs to be persisted so that work can carry on after an instance crash (and by crash, I mean something that terminates the instance or otherwise renders it inoperable and unrecoverable) then your data MUST NOT be on the root volume, but should be on another EBS volume which is attached to the instance. If and when that instance terminates or breaks irretrievably, your data is safe on that other volume - it can then be re-attached to a new instance for work to continue.

** the exception is where your instance is EBS-backed and you swapped root volumes - in this case, the root volume is left behind after the instance terminates because it wasn't part of the 'package' created by the AMI when you started it.

Comment: thanks Jonners. If I've read you right, my next steps should be to launch another EBS volume, attach it to my current EBS-backed instance, create the filesystem and mount it, and then configure Apache and MySQL to store their data on this new EBS volume. Once that's all done, how safe can I consider my data (relatively speaking). Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, that would be my recommendation. As to data 'safety', that's a matter of trust - the EBS infrastructure is designed to be always-on and backed-up, but nothing is guaranteed. Indeed, last month EC2 experienced a major EBS catastrophe in the EU region which resulted in a lot of lost data. It's the first time it's happened, and highly unusual, but proof that 99.999% safe isn't 100%. If the data is mission-critical, do what I and others do and export it somewhere else on a regular basis as a failsafe (a simple FTP to another site is probably a good starting-point).

Answer (score 0):

The other volume would be needed in case your server gets broken and you cannot start it. In such case you would just remove initial server, create a second one and attach the additional storage to the new server. You cannot attach root volume of one server to another.

Comment: "You cannot attach root volume of one server to another." -- yes you can, if the instance is EBS-backed. Stop instance #1, detach root volume, attach to instance #2 (either as root or secondary storage).